# Pick from n equal items, the one associated with the smallest number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I dont know how to explaind this but I'll give it a try. I have a `list1 = [('Lista-A', 2000), ('Lista-X', 1000), ('Lista-Z', 5000)])` then i will have a

```
list2 = [['Lista-A', 2000.0],
 ['Lista-A', 1000.0],
 ['Lista-A', 666.6666666666666],
 ['Lista-A', 500.0],
 ['Lista-A', 400.0],
 ['Lista-A', 333.3333333333333],
 ['Lista-X', 1000.0],
 ['Lista-X', 500.0],
 ['Lista-X', 333.3333333333333],
 ['Lista-X', 250.0],
 ['Lista-X', 200.0],
 ['Lista-X', 166.66666666666666],
 ['Lista-Z', 5000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 2500.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1666.6666666666667],
 ['Lista-Z', 1250.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 833.3333333333334]]
```

Now i need to pick the n biggest items from the list2 but everytime 2 or 3 or more items have the same numeric value, the function will need to go back to the first list and check which one of its items have the smallest numeric value the from the items with equal value, it'll have to pick the one that has the same "name" (Lista-A, Z or X) as the item from the first list with the smallest numeric value. I don't if its clear what i need to do.
I already tried to sort the list, but then i dont know to move on.

For this case I need the 6 biggest values, so the expected result would be

```
 list3 = [['Lista-Z', 5000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 2500.0],
 ['Lista-A', 2000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1666.6666666666667],
 ['Lista-Z', 1250.0],
 ['Lista-x', 1000.0]]
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to sort `list2` by descending value of each second item, and in cases of ties you want the item in `list1` corresponding to the first item to be the tie-breaker?

Comment: Could you maybe post the desired result for this example case above?

Comment: @Seb Exactly, sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but thats exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly

```
list1 = [('Lista-A', 2000), ('Lista-X', 1000), ('Lista-Z', 5000)]
list1 = dict(list1)  #Converted to dict for easy lookup

list2 = [['Lista-A', 2000.0],
 ['Lista-A', 1000.0],
 ['Lista-A', 666.6666666666666],
 ['Lista-A', 500.0],
 ['Lista-A', 400.0],
 ['Lista-A', 333.3333333333333],
 ['Lista-X', 1000.0],
 ['Lista-X', 500.0],
 ['Lista-X', 333.3333333333333],
 ['Lista-X', 250.0],
 ['Lista-X', 200.0],
 ['Lista-X', 166.66666666666666],
 ['Lista-Z', 5000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 2500.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1666.6666666666667],
 ['Lista-Z', 1250.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 833.3333333333334]]
list2.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], -list1.get(x[0], x[0])), reverse=True)

print(list2[:6])
```

**Output:**

```
[['Lista-Z', 5000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 2500.0],
 ['Lista-A', 2000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1666.6666666666667],
 ['Lista-Z', 1250.0],
 ['Lista-X', 1000.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way this can be done is with NumPy's [`lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html). First I'd map the first column to the corresponding numerical values:

```py
>>> tiebreakers = dict(list1)
>>> arr = np.array([(tiebreakers[a], b) for (a, b) in list2])
>>> arr
array([[2000.        , 2000.        ],
       [2000.        , 1000.        ],
       [2000.        ,  666.66666667],
       [2000.        ,  500.        ],
       [2000.        ,  400.        ],
       [2000.        ,  333.33333333],
       [1000.        , 1000.        ],
       [1000.        ,  500.        ],
       [1000.        ,  333.33333333],
       [1000.        ,  250.        ],
       [1000.        ,  200.        ],
       [1000.        ,  166.66666667],
       [5000.        , 5000.        ],
       [5000.        , 2500.        ],
       [5000.        , 1666.66666667],
       [5000.        , 1250.        ],
       [5000.        , 1000.        ],
       [5000.        ,  833.33333333]])
```

Then you can sort the array as required with `lexsort`:

```py
>>> order = np.lexsort((arr[:, 0], -arr[:, 1])) # Sorts by column 1 desc and column 0 asc
>>> order
array([12, 13,  0, 14, 15,  6,  1, 16, 17,  2,  7,  3,  4,  8,  5,  9, 10, 11])
>>> list3 = [list2[i] for i in order]
>>> list3[:6]
[['Lista-Z', 5000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 2500.0],
 ['Lista-A', 2000.0],
 ['Lista-Z', 1666.6666666666667],
 ['Lista-Z', 1250.0],
 ['Lista-X', 1000.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that would work but since this is for a school project, i can only use basic python and no packages.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, Rakesh's solution is ideal.